# Swift - Cast from [SKNode] to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: swift, sknode

I am beginner in swift language and currently i am developing some App (Game).
But i have problem when casting AnyObject to String or else, which is always give warning "Cast from [SKNode] to unrelated type 'String' always fails"

Here my code

```
var facets = [AnyObject]()
init () {
        facets = [
            [
                "id": "1",
                "lang": ["id": "Memori", "en": "Memory"]
            ],
            [
                "id": "2",
                "lang": ["id": "Kecepatan Berpikir", "en": "Speed"]
            ],
            [
                "id": "3",
                "lang": ["id": "Fungsi Eksekutif", "en": "Control"]
            ],
            [
                "id": "4",
                "lang": ["id": "Konsentrasi", "en": "Attention"]
            ],
            [
                "id": "5",
                "lang": ["id": "Pemecahan Masalah", "en": "Problem Solving"]
            ]
        ]
    }

func findFacetUsingId(id: String?) -> String? {
        if let id = id {
            for value in facets {
                var facet_id: String = value["id"] as! String
                if id == facet_id {
                    var names: Dictionary<String, String> = value["lang"] as! Dictionary<String, String>
                    return names[Lang.ID]
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Here the screenshot,
[image]

By the way, I got success when using this code

```
var facet_id: String = value.objectForKey("id") as! String
```

instead of

```
var facet_id: String = value["id"] as! String
```

But the App to be slow (very very slow)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works if you just do a little change:

```
func findFacetUsingId(id: String?) -> String? {
  if let id = id {
    for value in facets {
      var facet_id: String = value["id"] as! String
      if id == facet_id {
        var names: Dictionary<String, String> = value["lang"] as! Dictionary<String, String>
        return names["id"]
      }
    }
  }
return nil
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to explain "Lang" class, it will return "en" or "fr" based on prefered language.